# MariaDB won't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, mysql, apparmor, mariadb

Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 x64

If I try to start `mysqld` it fails and in the syslog I have

```
kernel: [ 2336.792423] audit: type=1400 audit(1470265086.730:518): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=11850 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=117 ouid=0
```

I added `/run/systemd/notify/` to apparmor, but I cannot add `run/systemd/notify` - "/" is missing

How can I fix this? I need MariaDB to run on a separate partition

I am using MariaDB with data folder on `/home/db/mysql`
I had a symlink configured to point to it from

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 14 iun 22 20:58 /var/lib/mysql -> /home/db/mysql`

and also had app armor profile configured:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Last Modified: Tue Jun 19 17:37:30 2007
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
#include <abstractions/base>
#include <abstractions/nameservice>
#include <abstractions/user-tmp>
#include <abstractions/mysql>
#include <abstractions/winbind>

capability dac_override,
capability sys_resource,
capability setgid,
capability setuid,

network tcp,

/etc/hosts.allow r,
/etc/hosts.deny r,

/etc/mysql/*.pem r,
/etc/mysql/conf.d/ r,
/etc/mysql/conf.d/* r,
/etc/mysql/*.cnf r,
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ r,
/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/*.so* mr,
/usr/sbin/mysqld mr,
/usr/share/mysql/** r,
/var/log/mysql.log rw,
/var/log/mysql.err rw,
/var/lib/mysql/ r,
/var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
/var/log/mysql/ r,
/var/log/mysql/* rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
/run/systemd/notify w,
/home/db/** rwk,
/home/db/mysql/** rwk,

/sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,

# Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
#include <local/usr.sbin.mysqld>
}
```

It previously failed on cd to `/home/db/mysql`, but fixed it by editing the `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` and setting `ProtectHome=false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several failed tries involving apparmor configuration, editing 
`/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to set the datadir, which failed, I went on a different approach.

1. Stopped the service (if started): `sudo service mysqld stop`
2. Purged the installation `apt-get purge mysqld*`
3. I removed everything involving mysql and mariadb (searched `/etc`, `/var` for them). You may want to back them up if you think you may need them for reference in the future.

   - mysql and mariadb configuration in `/etc/systemd/system`
   - mysql profile in `/etc/apparmor.d`
   - dir `/etc/mysql`
   - the symlink I had for `mysql` in `/var/lib` (my data is safe on `/home/db/mysql`). Skip this if your data is in `/var/lib/mysql`
4. Reinstalled `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`
5. Renamed the `/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql.bk` and created symlink for `/home/db/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql`
6. Set ownership to the symlink and `/home/db/mysql` for mysql:mysql

All works on reboot and it doesn't die anymore.

I can start and stop the service with `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

I guess the migration to systemd caused all this trouble. Maybe using the old init.d scripts is not the best way to do things, but it's the only way I found to keep MariaDB running after reboot, otherwise it kept crashing because of

```
kernel: [ 2336.792423] audit: type=1400 audit(1470265086.730:518): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=11850 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=117 ouid=0
```

Since some of the clients I was using gave `Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`, I had to create a symlink `sudo ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`. The link got removed on reboot though...

Therefore, I had to edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` files to set `socket   = /tmp/mysql.sock`. The debian.cnf says `DO NOT TOUCH!`, but I took the chances, since my.cnf says `Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location`. Note: a reboot was required to see the changes applied. Only restarting the service didn't apply them. Maybe some daemon should have been reloaded, but didn't know which one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed MariaDB 10.2 on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 and used symbolic links to point to the users' databases in their home directories. This worked fine for 10.0, but would now return errors

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
>
> [ERROR] InnoDB: os_file_readdir_next_file() returned -1 in directory ./, crash recovery may have failed for some .ibd files!

All files and directories were owned by mysql:mysql.
However thanks to the question poster I found in `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` the setting:

> `#` Prevent accessing /home, /root and /run/user
>
> ProtectHome=true

After setting this to `false` and `systemctl daemon-reload` MariaDB would start up normally.

Hopefully this helps somebody.